# Converting $\int_ 0^\pi \frac{RT}{V-b}-\frac{a}{V^2}dV$ to $a \int_ 0^\pi \frac{dV}{V^2}-RT \int_ 0^\pi \frac{dV}{V-b}$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

$$\int_ 0^\pi \frac{RT}{V-b}-\frac{a}{V^2}dV$$

This expression to

$$a \int_ 0^\pi \frac{ dV}{V^2}-RT \int_ 0^\pi \frac{dV}{V-b}$$

I am having difficulty in converting this expression to the other one.

Please help.
[image]

Real limits were from 10 to 5.

$\int_ \frac{dv}{V^2}$.
Not getting how to solve this to $\int_ \frac{-1}{V}$.

Comment: Should there be an $a$ somewhere in the second expression?

Comment: Yes.Forgot by mistake.

Comment: Okay so you start from
$$
\int_ 0^\pi \left( \frac{RT}{V-b}-\frac{a}{v^2} \right)dV
$$
Due to linearity, you can split this up into two integrals 
$$
\int_ 0^\pi \frac{RT}{V-b}\,dV ~- ~ \int_ 0^\pi  \frac{a}{v^2}\, dV
$$
and you can then just change the order of the two integrals
$$
-  \int_ 0^\pi  \frac{a}{v^2}\, dV ~+~ \int_ 0^\pi \frac{RT}{V-b}\,dV ~
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Brilliant.I can do it from here.

Comment: @MattiP. Please also share how did you think of this? How can this expression came to your mind and you knew how you can get there.

Comment: Glad to help. It's not easy to describe how I got it, but of course it requires that I'm comfortable with the rules of integration. Well, when you compare the first expression and the second expression, you can immediately spot two differences: There are two $\int$-signs instead of one; and that the order of the terms is reversed (in the latter, dividing by $V^2$ comes **before** $RT$). So those are hints that the terms should be split up and then the order has to be changed.

Comment: Also, another comment: Please check the signs of the terms. Without any changes to the integration limits, there should be a minus-sign on the first term, and a plus-sign on the second term (in the second expression). So are you sure that the limits of the integration have not changed?

Comment: Limits did not change when I saw that expression converting to other in my book.

Comment: I am not exactly getting your point why should limits change @MattiP..

Comment: I was wondering about the limits change due to the discrepancy between the signs. Look at the sign of the term $\frac{a}{V^2}dV$, for example. In the first expression it's minus, but in the second expression it's plus. So I think there's some error. But if we changed the limits like so:
$$
- \int_0^{\pi} \frac{a}{V^2}\, dV = \int_{\pi}^0 \frac{a}{V^2}\, dV
$$
then we get the correct sign ... So I was just wondering about that.

Comment: In that way.If we change limits of both of them,then we can get the desired result right.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @MattiP in the answer, they have not changed limits in my book.

Comment: I will send a photo of whole method in the question above.I have written it down with result.

Comment: Just give me 1min.

Comment: @MattiP. I have uploaded it.